# Jump to question in close queue

Tags: feature-request

**Scenario:**
I open a question tagged with C# (as an example). I see that there are close votes against the question. I also see that there has been a recent update made to the question and the close votes are no longer applicable.

**Suggestion:**
10k+ reputation users with the "access to moderator tools" privilege and X reputation against the C# tag should be able to navigate directly to the question in the close vote queue and vote as normal / vote for "Leave Open", if not revert / reset existing close votes.